# Getting TypeError: jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default(...)(...).fancybox is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, fancybox

> I tried almost everything but failed to customize fancybox.
> Something is Wrong with `$(".various").fancybox() please suggest any other way.

```
 import React, { Component } from "react";
// import fancybox from "@fancyapps/fancybox";
import $ from "jquery";

import { allUsersDispatch } from "../redux";
// const $ = require("jquery");
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import fancybox from "@fancyapps/fancybox";**I think Something is wrong with imports**
import "@fancyapps/fancybox";
// import { fancybox } from "jquery";
// import fancybox from "../../fancybox-master/dist/jquery.fancybox";
class Fancybox extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
```

> TypeError: jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default(...)(...).fancybox is not a function <-- I got this error on both functional and class component.. i am trying to sole this issue from a long time.

```
  componentDidMount() {
    $(".various").fancybox({   **Why this is not a FUNCTION PLEASE HELP**
      maxWidth: 800,
      maxHeight: 600,
      fitToView: false,
      width: "70%",
      height: "70%",
      autoSize: false,
      closeClick: false,
      openEffect: "none",
      closeEffect: "none",
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Hello{" "}
        <li>
          <li>
            <a
              className="various fancybox.iframe"
              href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/L9szn1QQfas?autoplay=1"
            >
              Youtube (iframe)
            </a>
          </li>
        </li>
      </div>
    );
  }
 
}
export default Fancybox;
```

Comment: Got this error : TypeError: jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default(...)(...).fancybox is not a function.

Comment: i am importing everthing i can but still getting error

Comment: (fancyBox already initialized) i did it but still getting error -> TypeError: jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default(...)(...).fancybox is not a function